# Paging3 how to remove item in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I have a lazyColumn to use paging3 ,
My datas from network and  need to use the list count to ask server get next datas
but now i need to remove some special item ,how can remove it ，i already to use PagingSource.invalidate to referesh my lazyColumn

Comment: Add your sample code for better understanding